# Expression Writing: Random variable inside bayesian (Notation)

Tags: probability, notation

What is the best, most clear way to denote this example.

Event $A$: outcomes $(0,1)$.

- $P(C)=P(B)$, if $A=1$
- $P(C) = 0$, if $A=0$

Which one is best

1. $P(C) = P(B|A=1)$, $A$: indicator random variable
2. $P(C) = P(B|A)$, $A$: indicator random variable
3. $P(C)= P(B| P(A) = 1)$
4. yours

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a random variable with two outcomes $0$ and $1$, then I would write
$$
P(C\mid A=0)=0\quad\text{and}\quad P(C\mid A=1)=P(B)
$$
or equivalently
$$
P(C\mid A=a)=a\cdot P(B),\quad a=0,1.
$$